# How do I complete the first Thieves Guild quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am currently in the city of Riften in Skyrim. I'm working on the quest **A Chance Encounter** where I've been asked to steal Madesi's ring out of the locked box in her merchant's stall. This quest initiates contact with the Thieve's Guild so it's important that I finish it.

I'm able to get behind the stall and pick the lock without being detected. When it comes to actually stealing the ring, I'm totally stumped. Even while sneaking, I can't seem to get out of sight when I go in front of the box. There is not looting option when I try and take it from behind. Here's a view of the stall:

[image]

I have no idea what I'm supposed to do. Short of chugging an invisibility potion, is there any way to nab this ring without getting caught? I'm sure I'm missing something.

Comment: I just discovered - the invisibility potion doesn't work, apparently. The effects are voided as soon as you interact with someone so that sucks :/

Comment: Put buckets on the heads of everyone who can see you!

Comment: @Tom - I thought about it but there's like six of 'em. That's a lot of buckets!

Comment: I'm 90% sure Madesi is male.

Comment: @Raven - I somehow find that very troubling because I thought for sure it/he/she was female....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just figured this out. You're not supposed to steal from the case on his stand. Go behind it and look down. There is a lock you can pick behind and under the stand and his strongbox is inside this area.

Comment: Yup, I also just figured that out. That's incredibly sneaky! Love it.

Comment: cheers dude, really helpful mate.

Comment: You can also fail, and still be accepted into the guild. I didn't know about the strongbox though. Clever.

Comment: This drove me crazy! I thought it was in the display case and tried many times to steal it. Although eventually I was successful. I found you could sort of jump up the side of the stand while crouching (remaining in stealth) and just hit the TAKE button repeatedly. I ended up stealing EVERYTHING. HAH.

Comment: Just look at the arrow in the screenshot... it's pointing to the strongbox inside the stand.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply steal the ring at night, when no one is there.